# How to invoke a HTML custom button based on a HTML dropdownlist menu

Tags: posts, wp-query, customization

**I am a WordPress beginner and want a help**

I created a HTML dropdown list like this:

```
<select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1">
    <option value="select you location">&#xf015 select your location</option>
    <option value="cairo">Cairo</option>
    <option value="alexanderia">Alexanderia</option>
    <option value="aswan">Aswan</option>
    <option value="port said">Port Said</option>
</select>
```

and also I created a HTML button like this:

```
<button type="button" name="restaurantpreview" type="submit" value="chefpreview">restaurantpreview</button>
```

I am trying to search about the code that I must use to :

- when a user select a value from dropdown list
- then the user click on my button
- I get this value to my custom page and preview the list of restaurants in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`admin-post.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)) or [`admin-ajax.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) (AJAX only) to allow your front-end form to interact with WordPress.

Setting this up will allow you to create an action where you use the `$_POST` array to find the content you're looking for with [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and print it out as the response to your request.

Here's a decent guide to both methods: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/handling-form-submissions/